# What is the correct way of accessing Hydra's current output directory?

Tags: python, fb-hydra

Assuming I prevent [Hydra](https://hydra.cc/) from changing the current working directory, how can I still retrieve the job's output directory (i.e., the folder Hydra created for storing the results of the particular job) from `main()`?

Ideally, I'd like a method that works regardless of whether it's a regular run or a multi-run. I know I can access the configuration through `hydra.core.hydra_config.HydraConfig.get()`, but it's unclear whether any of the settings there always map to the output folder. The [relevant tutorial page](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/working_directory/) discusses how to set the output folder but not how to retrieve it in the case we didn't change the cwd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it.

```
hydra_cfg = hydra.core.hydra_config.HydraConfig.get()
hydra_cfg['runtime']['output_dir']
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `hydra.job.chdir` is false, the python program will not automatically change directories when the function decorated by `@hydra.main` is invoked. This means any files you write or data that you save from your main function should show up in the same folder where you started the python process. You can check what this folder is with any of the following:

- Inspect [`hydra.runtime.cwd`](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/intro/#hydraruntime)
- Call [`hydra.utils.get_original_cwd()`](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/working_directory/#original-working-directory)
- Call a standard library function like `os.getcwd()`

If `hydra.job.chdir` is true, invoking the `@main`-decorated function will change the python program's working directory to the path [`hydra.run.dir`](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/intro/#hydrarun) (for single-run mode) or to the concatenated path [`hydra.sweep.dir/hydra.sweep.subdir`](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/intro/#hydrasweep) for multirun mode.

Calling `os.getcwd()` will work to figure out what this is at runtime.
You can also use the [`${hydra:}` resolver](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/intro/#resolvers-provided-by-hydra) to calculate this path in your config:

```yaml
single_run_dir: ${hydra:run.dir}
multi_run_dir: ${hydra:sweep.dir}/${hydra:sweep.subdir}
```

See also the [Customizing working directory pattern](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/workdir/) doc.

Answer (score 0):

The full path to the output dir can also be returned with:

```
hydra.core.hydra_config.HydraConfig.get().runtime.output_dir
```

See https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/working_directory/